# Removing get parameter from URL on click

Tags: python, django, get, tagging

I have a multiple tag filter system on my website, i.e. I can click a tag to filter by "foo", then click on another tag to filter by "bar" as well. When I click the tag, it appends a parameter to the url, as such:

- a. http://www.domain.com/?tag=foo, then
- b. http://www.domain.com/?tag=foo/?tag=bar.

Then, the current tags used to filter are displayed at the top of the page. I need to be able to click a tag, and remove its associated parameter from the url. If I clicked "bar" tag at the url given by "b", I would expect the url "a". How can I manipulate the URL as such?

Currently, if you click a tag, it removes ALL tags from the filter (just a simple redirect back to the main domain), because I haven't been able to find a better way to play with the url.

EDIT:
Add tag

```
{% for tag in value.tags %}
    {% if tag.name %}
        <a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}?tag={{ tag.name.strip }}">
        {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Remove

```
{% for tag in tag_filters %} 
    <a href='/'>
    {{ tag }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work...

```
{% for tag in tag_filters %} 
    {% with "/?tag="|add:tag as to_cut %}
    <a href='{{ request.get_full_path|cut:to_cut }}'>
    {% endwith %}
    {{ tag }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

...although this might be better solved with a single query parameter which can take multiple strings, like...

```
http://www.domain.com/?tags=foo+bar+baz
```

...and using JavaScript to manipulate the URL, since it's much more flexible.

Comment: I think I might end up using a single querystring, but I'm not sure yet (working within a pre-existing structure). Thanks!